# How to reset a svg coordinates on clicking a second time in Snap.svg

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I want to create an icon that turns into a close button when clicking on it and on clicking again on the button, it turns into the original icon again. So far I have managed to do the first part of the code. I know that I can use an if else condition but I don't know what to check for.  If you are looking for a jsfiddle, I'm sorry since there is no cdn for snap.svg yet.

```
 <span class="bars" data-icon-name="bars">
          <svg id="svg"></svg> 
 </span>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var Paper = Snap('#svg'); 
    var linepaths = Paper.line(20, 20, 100, 20);
    var linepaths1 = Paper.line(20, 33, 100, 33);
    var linepaths3 = Paper.line(20, 46, 100, 46);
    Paper.attr({
        stroke:'#fff',
        strokeWidth: 7
    });        
    Paper.click(
       function (){
       linepaths.animate({x1:20,y1:20,x2:75,y2:75},500);                              
       linepaths1.animate({x1:20,y1:75,x2:75,y2:20},500); 
       linepaths3.animate({x1:0,y1:0,x2:0,y2:0},1);  
       linepaths3.attr({
        stroke:'#2ecc71',
        strokeWidth: 7
         });   
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do a basic toggle I guess, it depends how you want it to work a bit..

```
Paper.click( function() { if( toggle ) {
                            buttonOn();
                            toggle = false;
                        } else { 
                            buttonOff(); 
                            toggle = true; } 
                    } );

function buttonOn() {
           linepaths.animate({x1:20,y1:20,x2:75,y2:75},500);                              
           linepaths1.animate({x1:20,y1:75,x2:75,y2:20},500); 
           linepaths3.animate({x1:0,y1:0,x2:0,y2:0},1);  
           linepaths3.attr({
            stroke:'#2ecc71',
            strokeWidth: 7
           });
};

 function buttonOff() {
    linepaths.animate({x1:20,y1:20,x2:100,y2:20},500);                              
           linepaths1.animate({x1:20,y1:33,x2:100,y2:33},500); 
           linepaths3.animate({x1:20,y1:46,x2:100,y2:46},1);  
           linepaths3.attr({
            stroke:'#2ecc71',
            strokeWidth: 7
           });
};
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2UZr2/5/

Comment: Thanks, its a little buggy but this is what I wanted to do.